# Read many files, compute something, save results in dataframe (R)

Tags: r

I have around 100 files (long filenames) with data from a simulation. Topic is the degradation of two substances, so I have 3 relevant columns: time, relative concentration of substance 1 (Sub1, from 1.0 to zero) and relative conc. of substance 2 (Sub2).

I want to read the files, determine the time when i.e. 99 % of each substrate are degraded and save the appropriate times in a dataframe. Right now I save the outcome in text files but thats very uncomfortable, as you will find.

```
names<-dir(pattern="txt")
z <- 0.99 #degradation level
a <- 1-z
for (n in names){
   data <- read.table(file=n,header=T)
   attach(data)
   matchs1 <- Time[abs(Sub1-a)==min(abs(Sub1-a))]  
   matchs2 <- Time[abs(Sub2-a)==min(abs(Sub2-a))]
   degrad <- cbind(matchs1,matchs2)
   setwd("C:/.../subdirectory")
   write.table(degrad, file=paste(n,"99",".txt"),sep=" ",row.names=FALSE)
}
```

In stead of writing files I would like to write the result (degrad) in a dataframe in consecutive rows.

Since I am still a beginner I think there's also an easier way to do all this?

Thank you in advance for your help ...

Comment: What if concentration `0.01` appears, say, twice for substance 1 but only once for the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use a `for` loop here, but using anything else won't likely see big improvements in speed because the overhead of the `for` loop is minimal compared to reading data in.

To get a data.frame just change your `for` loop a little to output to a data frame which you can pre-allocate with the number of rows equal to the number of files

```
# Pre-allocate results data.frame
res <- data.frame( matchs1 = numeric(length(names)) , matchs2 = numeric(length(names)) )

#  Fill it
for (i in 1:length(names)){
   data <- read.table(file=names[i],header=T)
   matchs1 <- with( data, Time[abs(Sub1-a)==min(abs(Sub1-a))] )  
   matchs2 <- with( data , Time[abs(Sub2-a)==min(abs(Sub2-a))] )
   res[i,] <- cbind(matchs1,matchs2) 
}
```

You should *absolutely not* use `attach`. Use `with` instead. I wasn't able to test this completely because I do not have access to your files and data, but I *think* this will work.

Comment: I have another question and maybe you've got an idea. Is it possible to do the calculation of the matches in another `for`-loop? So that the degradation level is a variable j (e. g. for (j in `seq(0,1,by=0.01))`). I tried a lot but nothing worked so far.

Answer (score 2):

The framework I usually use in these cases is:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(file_list, function(file_name) {
  # open file_name, do whatever processing
  # then return result as a data.frame (with data for just this one file,
  # then rbind will bind everything together)
  # in your example that would be the data.frame "degrad"
})) -> your_combined_dataframe
```

And if you use `data.table`'s instead, you can replace the `do.call(rbind,` by `rbindlist(`

Comment: You could also use foreach with `.combine=rbind` and get some speedup, especially if you use `%dopar%` to compute/read in parallel.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I keep having problems to use lapply. So I chose Simons answer, because I could apply it faster.