# R: problems constructing nested for-loop and saving results

Tags: r, for-loop

This is a question which is based on a question I asked before: [Read many files, compute something, save results in dataframe (R)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17074277/read-many-files-compute-something-save-results-in-dataframe-r) .

Still I have around 100 files with data from a simulation. Topic is the degradation of two substances, so I have 3 relevant columns: time (in minutes), relative concentration of substance 1 (Sub1, from 1.0 to zero) and relative conc. of substance 2 (Sub2).

This works fine to determine certain degradation levels, which I have to enter manually:

```
z <- 0.25 #Abbaugrad
a <- 1-z

setwd("H:/...")
names<-dir(pattern="Data.txt")
result <- data.frame( matchs1 = numeric(length(names)) , matchs2 =    numeric(length(names)) )
for (i in 1:length(names)){
  data <- read.table(file=names[i],header=T)
  matchs1 <- with( data, Time[abs(Sub1-a)==min(abs(Sub1-a))] )  
  matchs2 <- with( data , Time[abs(Sub2-a)==min(abs(Sub2-a))] )
  result[i,] <- cbind(matchs1,matchs2) 
  }
```

Now I wanted to automate the process so I don't have to enter degradation levels but the results are computed in a nested for-loop.

First I thought it might be better for future ideas to work with a datalist, e. g. for plotting some data from this files, so I did:

```
filelist <- list.files(pattern = "Data.txt")
datalist <- lapply(filelist, function(xx)read.table(xx,header=T))
```

This worked fine to plot some runs from the simulation.

```
plot(datalist[[1]][,3], type="l",col="red")
for (i in 1:10){
   lines(datalist[[i]][,3],col="red")  
   }
```

The cause for trying to construct the following loop is that I want to find out the mean run out of the 100. I think I have to find out the time when 1 % to 100 % are degraded for each run and then calculate the mean of each level.

Now my simple try for just one substance:

```
test <- data.frame(matrix(ncol=99, nrow = 100) ) #100 runs, 99 levels
for (i in 1:length(datalist)){
  for (j in seq(0.01,0.99,by=0.01)){
   matchs1 <- with( datalist[[i]], Time[abs(Sub1-j)==min(abs(Sub1-j))] )  
   level <- paste('l',j,sep="")
   test[j,] <- cbind(matchs1,level)
   }}
```

I wanted to construct a new dataframe where the result for each level (from 0.01 to 1) is saved in a single column. Then I could calculate the mean for each coloumn an rbind it. But I fail already to compute the data frame.

Maybe there is also an easier way to get the mean of different time-series.

I would really appreciate any help.

Edit:
It's hard for me to provide sample data, because I have got 100 files. In each one of them there are three relevant columns: Time, Sub1, Sub2. You can imagine it like that:

```
Time    Sub1    Sub2
0       1.0000  1.0000
60      0.9511  0.9888
120     0.9022  0.9555 
...
24000   0.0101  0.0891
```

I want to compute the mean run, so for each of the hundred files I have to calculate the time, when 0.01, 0.02, 0.03 ... 0.97, 0.98, 0.99 are degraded. Then I want to calculate the mean of i. e. all times, where 0.01 are degraded. The same for 0.02, 0.03 and so on. In the end I should have 99 times in ascending order.

Is it possible to attach files? I found no option to do that.

Edit 2:

The output of dput for the datalist obtained by

```
names <- dir(pattern="Data.txt")
datalist <- lapply(names, read.table, header=TRUE)
```

is:

```
> dput(head(datalist[[1]]))
structure(list(Time = c(0L, 60L, 120L, 180L, 240L, 300L), Sub0_Abs = c(1.49899, 
1.49568, 1.49544, 1.49533, 1.49521, 1.49507), Sub0_Rel = c(1, 
0.9978, 0.9976, 0.9976, 0.9975, 0.9974), Sub1_Abs = c(1.49899, 
1.49899, 1.49899, 1.49899, 1.49899, 1.49899), Sub1_Rel = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1), TP = c(0.15, 0.1579, 0.1584, 0.1586, 0.1589, 
0.1592), TA = c(0.13, 0.16, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.22), Sub_Inflow = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("Time", "Sub0_Abs", "Sub0_Rel", "Sub1_Abs", 
"Sub1_Rel", "TP", "TA", "Sub_Inflow"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

> dput(head(datalist[[2]]))
structure(list(Time = c(0L, 60L, 120L, 180L, 240L, 300L), Sub0_Abs = c(1.49899, 
1.49284, 1.49234, 1.49207, 1.49176, 1.49141), Sub0_Rel = c(1, 
0.9959, 0.9956, 0.9954, 0.9952, 0.9949), Sub1_Abs = c(1.49899, 
1.49899, 1.49899, 1.49899, 1.49899, 1.49899), Sub1_Rel = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1), TP = c(0.15, 0.1647, 0.1658, 0.1664, 0.1671, 
0.1679), TA = c(0.13, 0.21, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.37), Sub_Inflow = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("Time", "Sub0_Abs", "Sub0_Rel", "Sub1_Abs", 
"Sub1_Rel", "TP", "TA", "Sub_Inflow"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

The relevant columns are Time, Sub0_Rel and Sub1_Rel. In my earlier question I tried to shorten the names a little bit.

Comment: You would really benefit from learning to use `lapply` and `sapply`. They are actually quite easy to use. If you provided some reproducible data in your question, it would be easier for people to help you.

Comment: Hello Roland, thank you for your help. I'm trying to learn lapply by studying examples, but it's somehow difficult to learn because it's not so 'intuitive' at the first sight. ... I added some sample data so one can imagine the data structure.

Answer (score 0):

As @Roland said, it is hard to help you without some example data.  I took a shot at writing some code for a bunch of z values, but, of course (without data), the code is untested.  Perhaps it will help you get started.

```
# try with a bunch of z values
z <- c(0.25, 0.45, 0.72, 0.83)
a <- 1-z

setwd("H:/...")
# read in all of the data and save to a list
names <- dir(pattern="Data.txt")
datalist <- lapply(names, read.table, header=TRUE)
matchs <- lapply(datalist, function(dat) 
    cbind(dat[which.min(abs(dat$Sub1-a)), ]), dat[which.min(abs(dat$Sub2-a)), ])
```

Right around here I get lost, because I'm not sure what you're trying to plot ...

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried your code, but I get the error message `Object 'dat' not found` ...

Comment: If you post the results to the following two commands, I will try to troubleshoot.  `dput(head(datalist[[1]]))` and `dput(head(datalist[[2]]))`.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I had an idea that might make things a bit simpler.  How about using linear interpolation instead of finding the nearest sub value for each number in long sequence?  You can do this with the `approx()` function.  For example, define a function to calculate the mean time for a sequence of subs.

```
mean.time <- function(sub, time, points=seq(0.01, 0.99, by=0.01)) {
    linear.interp <- approx(x=sub, y=time, xout=points)
    mean(linear.interp$y, na.rm=TRUE)
    }
```

Then you can apply this function to each element of your list of data frames, once for sub1 and once for sub2.  (I assumed that you were interested in `Sub0_Rel` and `Sub1_Rel`.  If that's not the case, you will have to edit that part of the code.)

```
match1 <- sapply(datalist, function(dat) mean.time(dat$Sub0_Rel, dat$Time))
match2 <- sapply(datalist, function(dat) mean.time(dat$Sub1_Rel, dat$Time))
```